# cassandra: How to fetch column names from Cassandra table in alphabetically sorted order?

Tags: cql

In Cassandra once table is created,post which if we describe table it first shows partitioning key columns,next clustering key columns and than remaining columns in alphabetically sorted order.I have one real time business requirement where i have to take indexOf(column_name) when all columns are alphabetically sorted.Is there anyway by which we can sort all columns of Cassandra table alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

```
use system_schema;
select column_name from columns  where keyspace_name = 'nameofkeyspace' and table_name = 'tablename';
```

The table already have column_name as clustering key and is sorted by clustering key - so you will always get the sorted list of columns;